# Disabling wordpress wp-login.php

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

I created my own login page. And used this following code for warning message if username and password empty.

```
function verify_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {
$login_page  = home_url( '/login/' );
if( $username == "" || $password == "" ) {
    wp_redirect( $login_page . "?login=empty" );
    exit;
  }
}
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'verify_username_password', 1, 3);
```

And disabled wp-login.php with this following code:

```
if (is_super_admin()) {
header('Location: wp-admin.php'); 
}
else {
header('Location: index.php');
}
```

but when i go to wp-login.php it redirects me to login page.
I want to redirect to homepage if user is not admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

"$pagenow (string) used in wp-admin"

```
add_action('init','custom_login');

function custom_login(){
 global $pagenow;
 if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow && $_GET['action']!="logout") {
  wp_redirect('index.php');
  exit();
 }
}
```

Comment: Tried this code. But my form doesn't show empty error message.

Comment: It redirects again homepage when username and pass is empty. I am using with above codes in functions.php